# Import multiple Spreadsheets into 1 Sheet using AppScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, append

I have a script that imports data from different google sheets into one sheet, it works perfectly except the fact that every time when I'm running the script the imported data starts further down in the sheet. What do I need to change in the script that every time i start the script it will push the data starting the first row of the sheet?

````
function getData() {
  get_IDs=["1pkcy4jx14odSN-Ir2Nqai89_0dJc7RiLapWxRWIURj4","1J8_cZsjEa9c8vktPBvqGvcdwUBAVkWT3NSdTnXp6tMk"];

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet =ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  copySheet.getRange('A1:Z').clear();

  for(z=0;z<get_IDs.length;z++)
  {

  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.openById(get_IDs[z]);
  var sheets =ss1.getSheetByName("Export Department");
  var sheetsRange = sheets.getDataRange();
  var sheetsValues = sheetsRange.getValues();

  for(var y = 1;y<sheetsValues.length;y++)
  {
    copySheet.appendRow(sheetsValues[y]);
  }

  }
  
}```
````

Comment: *Why are you setting the rows individually?!*

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setvaluesvalues) instead of `appendRow()` and increment a counter by the number of rows on each import:

```
function getData() {
  get_IDs = ["1pkcy4jx14odSN-Ir2Nqai89_0dJc7RiLapWxRWIURj4", "1J8_cZsjEa9c8vktPBvqGvcdwUBAVkWT3NSdTnXp6tMk"]

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3")
  copySheet.getRange('A1:Z').clear()

  let pasteRow = 1

  for (z = 0; z < get_IDs.length; z++) {
    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(get_IDs[z])
    var sheets = ss1.getSheetByName("Export Department")
    var sheetsRange = sheets.getDataRange()
    var sheetsValues = sheetsRange.getValues()

    sheetsValues.splice(0, 1)

    copySheet.getRange(pasteRow, 1, sheetsValues.length, sheetsValues[0].length).setValues(sheetsValues)
    pasteRow += sheetsValues.length
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I'm trying to import and append 15 sheets, but I think this ist to big for that script. It starts executing the script but is loading the whole time and never really finish to get all of the sheets. Do you have any better solution to get all these 15 sheets?

Comment: @JuliaNeugebauer what is your execution time limit? Aside from one extra `getRange()` call the script isn’t really more costly than when you have in the question